# Check whether string is valid HTML tag

Tags: python

I'm parsing html documents in python using beautifulsoup and the lxml parser.
These html documents can be incredibly dirty, having almost arbitrary strings as tag names.

I want to check whether a given tag name is a valid html tag. Is there any method in python to do this, other than manually creating a list of all valid html tags?

Comment: This is not what you want, but I want to point out the list approach is a valid one, and the list isn't too long to put in a file somewhere: https://www.way2tutorial.com/html/tag/index.php

Comment: Oh, that list isn't too long at all! For some reason I thought the list of valid html tags was much, much larger. A whitelist of valid tags seems like a decent approach then.

Though for maintainability, it would be nice if there was some way to programmatically retrieve an up-to-date list from a definitive source, in case new tags are added.